# One to Many options doesn't appear in Model Form Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, modelform

I am very new to Django and struggling to figure wrong what am I missing in Django Model Form. I want to display a drop-down with predefined values in the form but for some reason, the options never appear. Following is the code from models.py

```
LOAN_STATUS = (
    ('m', 'Maintenance'),
    ('o', 'On loan'),
    ('a', 'Available'),
    ('r', 'Reserved'),
)

class Status (models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(
            max_length=50,
            choices=LOAN_STATUS,
            blank=True,
            default='m',
        )
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Status'

class Property(models.Model):
   propertyID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   status = models.ForeignKey(Status, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

   def __str__(self):
      return self.propertyTitle
```

Following is the code from ModelForm

```
class CreateAdvertisementForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Property
        exclude = ['propertyID']
        fields = ('status',)
```

Following is the code from my Template

```
{% block body %}
<form method="POST" class="post-form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}

    <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
</form>{% endblock %}
```

Please help me understand what is going wrong.

[image]

Comment: in your Property model __str__ function you refer to attribute propertyTitle but you haven't specified it as an attribute of the model. This will probably cause you problems. Does your form still display an empty dropdown?

Comment: This is because I didn't want to paste the entire model. I do have a property called propertyTitle

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the models field like this instead of under Meta as you have it:

```
class Status (models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(
                max_length=50,
                choices=LOAN_STATUS,
                blank=True,
                default='m',
            )
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Status'
```

and increase the max_length to a number that is larger than the character amount of the longest word in your LOAN_STATUS choices. I think the way you have it there would be a problem because the max_length is 1 character, but all of your choices have more than 1 character. Maybe since the choice display has 1 character it will work, but I'm fairly sure it will check the second value.

Also, I always specify fields value in my forms:

```
class CreateAdvertisementForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Property
        fields = ('status',)
```

This tells it exactly what fields you want to render. It may seem like overkill since you only have 1 field in your model it should be obvious, but I think this is best practice for security reasons. Maybe someone else can give their input on it.

Comment: Thank You for the observations. I agree with the said changes and have modified the question. Unfortunately, still no luck.

Comment: @angraonhunt - What exactly is going wrong? Is it an empty dropdown menu?

Comment: Intrestingly when I check my db.sqlite3 file Status table is empty. Is it correct? This is the best guess I can come up with. :(

Comment: Yes, It is an empty dropdown.

Comment: @angraonhunt -  run makemigrations and migrate again. Since you specified your field under meta the column probably was not created.

Comment: @angraonhunt - you should put your screenshot in your question if you want to include it.

Comment: Added the screenshot. I ran makemigrations and migrate. Also I checked migrations. The Status table was successfully created.
  migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Status',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('status', models.CharField(blank=True, choices=[('m', 'Maintenance'), ('o', 'On loan'), ('a', 'Available'), ('r', 'Reserved')], default='m', max_length=50)),
            ],
            options={
                'db_table': 'Status',
            },
        ),

Answer (score 0):

Try to refresh your DataBase,

```
python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb
```

then makemigrations and migrate

```
python manage.py makrmigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

After a day of struggle, I finally got it working. However, I am really not sure if I understand it correctly. I ended up inserting values into my database using python console. According to me, Django should handle this automatically because I have already defined all possible values in models.py. What am I missing here?